# Does anyone know to how draw a roundabout in 2D and how to simulate it in java?

Tags: java

Does anyone know to how draw a roundabout in 2D and how to do a roundabout simulation it in java? At least some guidelines how to proceed and the necessary formula required to perform the simulation?

Comment: -1 what did you try? please show us your efforts

Answer (score 2):

There is no such formula.   Indeed the notion of a "formula" for a simulation doesn't even make sense.

The correct answer depends on the simulation framework you are using / building, the granularity of your simulation, the road rules you are implementing, whether (and how) you are dealing with "cars" that don't obey the rules ... and so on.

Even drawing a roundabout depends on the context (e.g. your graphics framework), whether it needs to be realistic, and whether it needs to fit into something else (e.g. a larger simulation).

You will most likely need to work this all out for yourself.  (And reading between the lines ... working it out yourself is most likely what your teacher wants you to do!)